# Extract the request from test step

Tags: soapui

Can anyone please help me to find a wat to extract the request from test step in soapUI?
I have tried with the below groovy
def extRequest = test step.properties["Request"].value;
It's throwing groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testStep for class:

My testcase name is RESTRequest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)
```